# Compare sums in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table:

```
System | Pcs | Article
----------------------
s1     | 1   | a1
s2     | 1   | a1
...................
s1     | 5   | a2
s2     | 2   | a2
s2     | 3   | a2
...................
s1     | 8   | a3
s2     | 1   | a3
s2     | 2   | a3
s2     | 3   | a3
```

and need to `SUM` pieces of an article in different systems and compare it each other, so the result should be like this:

```
System | SUM(Pcs) | Article | Check
------------------------------------
s1     | 1        | a1      | OK
s2     | 1        | a1      | OK
s1     | 5        | a2      | OK
s2     | 5        | a2      | OK
s1     | 8        | a3      | Not OK
s2     | 6        | a3      | Not OK
```

`Check` column is telling, that the sums of same article in different systems are equal.

Is it clear to understand? How can I do that?

Comment: Where is the `Check` column coming from?

Comment: are there any other system or just two for every article?

Comment: It tells, that sums of same article in different systems are eual

Comment: @JW: they will be three, but two for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this query, it doesn't matter if there are unknown number of System per Article.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  Article, System, SUM(pcs) Pcs
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP   BY Article, System
),
records2
AS
(
    SELECT  Article, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT pcs) totalCount
    FROM    records
    GROUP   BY Article
)
SELECT  a.System, a.Pcs, a.Article,
        CASE WHEN b.totalCount = 1 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOT OK' END AS [Check]
FROM    records a
        INNER JOIN records2 b
            ON a.Article = b.Article
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5681/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦═════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ SYSTEM ║ PCS ║ ARTICLE ║ CHECK  ║
╠════════╬═════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ s1     ║   1 ║ a1      ║ OK     ║
║ s2     ║   1 ║ a1      ║ OK     ║
║ s1     ║   5 ║ a2      ║ OK     ║
║ s2     ║   5 ║ a2      ║ OK     ║
║ s1     ║   8 ║ a3      ║ NOT OK ║
║ s2     ║   6 ║ a3      ║ NOT OK ║
╚════════╩═════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a wonderful solution! I've never heard about with statement.... :-)

Comment: search for `Common Table Expression`

Comment: there is a just small problem if there are more then 1 results with the same `SUM(pcs)` - it results to `Not OK`..

Comment: can you give me a sample record of that `:)` it needs just a little tweak.

Comment: I'll try it, but it takes a several minutes, because the problem still can be (or probably be) on my side :-))

Answer (score 1):

Please find below query will helps you

```
SELECT 
    [System], 
    SumOfPcs, 
    Article,
    CASE WHEN SumOfPcs = OtherArticleSum THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOT OK' END AS [Check]
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        [System],
        sum(Pcs) as SumOfPcs,
        Article,
        (SELECT 
                SUM(demoin.Pcs)
            FROM demo demoin
            WHERE NOT (demoin.[System] = demoout.[System] AND demoin.Article = demoout.Article) 
                AND demoin.Article = demoout.Article
        ) AS OtherArticleSum

    FROM demo demoout
    GROUP BY [System], Article
) tbl
```